# How do I add custom properties to excel document using c#?

Tags: c#, excel, automation, com, office-interop

I am trying to add properties to the excel document (few properties which will make the document confidential). I tried few ways I found on internet, but either I get exception or nothing happens. Can someone tell me where I am making mistake?

1. Way: Here I get System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException.

```
     class Program
    {
        static Application excelApp;
        static Workbook excelWorkBook;
        static Worksheet excelWorkSheet;

        string name1 = "myprop1";
        string val1 = "myvalue1";

        string name2 = "myprop2";
        string val2 = "myvalue2";

        string name3 = "longid";
        int val3 = 3;

        string name4 = "id";
        int val4 = 2;


        excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties(name1,val1);
        excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties(name2, val2);
        excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties(name3, val3);
        excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties(name4, val4);
    }
```

2. Way: Here nothing happens. Properties are not changed and there is no exception.

```
 excelWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Add("myprop1", "myvalue1");
 excelWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Add("myprop2", "myvalue2");
 excelWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Add("myprop3", 3);
 excelWorkSheet.CustomProperties.Add("myprop4", 2);
```

3. Try is giving me: System.ArgumentException:Value does not fall within the expected range.

```
excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties["myprop1"].Text = "myvalue1";
excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties["myprop2"].Text = "myvalue2";
excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties["myprop3"].Value = 3;
excelWorkBook.CustomDocumentProperties["myprop4"].Value = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
Word.Document doc = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties docprops = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty projectNameProperty = null;

    try
    {
        doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
        docprops = doc.CustomDocumentProperties as 
            Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties;
        projectNameProperty = docprops.Add(
            "Customer Name",
            false,
            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
            "Add-in Express");
        doc.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (projectNameProperty != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(projectNameProperty);
        if (docprops != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docprops);
        if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    }
```

To modify custom properties you can use the following code:

```
 Word.Document doc = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties docprops = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperty projectNameProperty = null;

    try
    {
        doc = WordApp.ActiveDocument;
        docprops = doc.CustomDocumentProperties as 
            Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties;
        projectNameProperty = docprops["Customer Name"];
        projectNameProperty.Value = "Acme Inc.";
        doc.Save();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (projectNameProperty != null) 
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(projectNameProperty);
        if (docprops != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(docprops);
        if (doc != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    }
```

Read more about document properties in the [Working with Word document properties, bookmarks, content controls and quick parts](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/08/27/word-document-properties-bookmarks-content-controls-quick-parts/) article.

If you still have problems with accessing document properties I'd suggest using the late binding technology by using the `Type.InvokeMember` method to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

For c# , it worked for me,

```
 

      Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties  prps;
    
       prps = (Office.DocumentProperties)this.CustomDocumentProperties;
       prps.Add("Transaction Type", false, Microsoft.Office.Core
                .MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "Balance", missing);
```

Here "Transaction Type" is key, "Balance" is value